# Send an instance of object in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

I have a problem with transferring an object to WCF service from client. I can't use standard contract definitions since it's a generic service for several different apps.

Server and client are both have an assembly in which transferred type is defined, so server can deserialize object instance from a SOAP message. First I tried to send this object "as is", but got message about not expected contract name: "Type 'Type Name' with data contract name 'X:Y' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer."

After research I've learned that there are several methods to fix this problem:
1. use KnownType[] attribute (this is not possible since I don't know on compile-time all the types)
2. use static contracts (similar)
3. use DataContractResolver (that's ok since I can look assemblies and try to find those types)

After learning this article - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WCF-Data-Contract-Resolver-7de9b8b4#content - I've created an attribute to substitute Resolver in my project (since it is IIS-hosted):

```
public class DataContractResolverAttribute: Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    private Type _resolverType = null;

    public DataContractResolverAttribute (Type resolver)
    {
        _resolverType = resolver;
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters (OperationDescription description, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior (OperationDescription description, ClientOperation proxy)
    {
        AddResolverToOperation(description);
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior (OperationDescription description, DispatchOperation dispatch)
    {
        AddResolverToOperation(description);
    }

    public void Validate (OperationDescription description)
    {
    }

    private void AddResolverToOperation (OperationDescription description)
    {
        DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dcs = description.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
        if (dcs != null)
        {
            dcs.DataContractResolver = Activator.CreateInstance(_resolverType) as DataContractResolver;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I've assigned this attribute to operation:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(string))]
    [DataContractResolver(typeof(CustomResolver))]
    RuleResultData ExecuteRuleObj (object context, int ruleId);
```

CustomResolver is descendand from DataContractResolver:

```
class CustomResolver: DataContractResolver
{
    public override Type ResolveName (string typeName, string typeNamespace, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
    {
        // ... not significant here ...
    }

    public override bool TryResolveType (Type type, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, out XmlDictionaryString typeName, out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
    {
        // ... not significant here ...
    } 
}
```

On debugging I see that Resolver is successfully substituted (set a breakpoint in AddResolverToOperation ), but on call I don't see any effect (breakpoints in ResolveName and TryResolveType are not triggered).

Please give a clue about such annoying resolver's behavior.

Thanks in advance.
Alexey Vishnyakov, Russia.

Comment: Would be great if you can post on how your WCF service method looks like and then the client code where you are passing the object. The object definition which you are trying to pass?

Comment: Hmm, it's look like I have a bug in different location. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Well, there is issue in serializing (not DEserializing) my object. Due to lack of time, I've serialized it manually via BinaryFormatter and transferred like a byte array. It is not fair play, but it works.